# calling one xslt file from base xslt - xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I went through many other similar questions and answers in stackoverflow. But still not able to resolve the issue. If anyone can help me with it that would be really great.I am using call template to call one small xslt file from my larger xslt

My small xslt(WorkOrders.xsl) is very simple. Below is the part of my xslt:

```
      <xsl:template match="GetWorkOrder">
    <tns:Work>
      <tns:description>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns0:WORKORDERS_ITEM/ns0:DESCRIPTION"/>
      </tns:description>
<tns:workOrderNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns0:WORKORDERS_ITEM/ns0:WORKORDER"/>
      </tns:workOrderNumber>
    </tns:Work>
  </xsl:template>
```

I want to call WorkOrder.xsl from my base xslt. i am using the import statement
part of my base xslt. (i have got rid of the extra xml definitions to shorten the xslt for this question)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java">
  <xsl:import href="../Transformation/WorkOrders.xsl"/>
  <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
    <!--SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY.-->
    <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="XSD">
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../Schema/Sample.xsd"/>
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="OutputParameters"
                                       namespace="****"/>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
    </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
    <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:target type="XSD">
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../Schema/Sample1.xsd"/>
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="GetResponse" namespace="*****"/>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:target>
    </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
    <!--GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 12.1.3.0.0(XSLT Build 140529.0700.0211) AT [THU SEP 26 14:08:57 EDT 2019].-->
  </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
  <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:GetResponse>
      <tns:Response>
        <Work>
          <xsl:call-template name="GetWorkOrder"></xsl:call-template>
        </Work>
      </tns:Response>
    </tns:GetResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I receive an error message saying GetWorkOrder template is been called but not defied. Not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template isn't named `GridWalkOrder`, you've defined it as matching an element of that name rather than naming the template. Use

```
<xsl:template name="GetWorkOrder">
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo.. i couldnt catch it.. fixed it.. But now i get empty response..Am i calling the template correctly?

Comment: Are you not even getting a `tns:Work` element out?

Comment: Thanks. it worked fine now. I was missing an element in the xpath